# Adding data to HDF5 Dataset

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

```
import numpy as np
import h5py

x1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
y1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
z1 = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
namesList = ['ID', 'Name', 'Path']
ds_dt = np.dtype({'names': namesList, 'formats': ['S32'] * 4})

rec_arr = np.rec.fromarrays([x1, y1, z1], dtype=ds_dt)
test = [[], [], []]

hdf5_file = h5py.File("test.h5", "w")
structure = hdf5_file.create_group('structure')
structure.create_dataset('images', data=test, compression='gzip', maxshape=(None,3))
structure['images'].resize((structure['images'].shape[0] + rec_arr.shape[0]), axis=0)
structure['images'][-rec_arr.shape[0]:] = rec_arr
```

I am starting with an empty dataset and I am trying to add data to that data set. When I view the file, nothing has been added and the dataset is empty. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

We can add the data directly to the .h5 file when creating the new dataset. The following code worked for me to write rec_arr to the file, and I added the 'with' statement to ensure it is closed properly.

```
import numpy as np
import h5py

x1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
y1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
z1 = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
namesList = ['ID', 'Name', 'Path']
ds_dt = np.dtype({'names': namesList, 'formats': ['S32'] * 4})

rec_arr = np.rec.fromarrays([x1, y1, z1], dtype=ds_dt)

with h5py.File("test.h5", "w") as hdf5_file:
    structure = hdf5_file.create_group('structure')
    structure.create_dataset('images', data=rec_arr, compression='gzip', maxshape=(rec_arr.shape))
```

Comment: How would you add more data to the dataset later on? For example, I want to add another row like [5, f, 10] right below that data. How would I do that?

Comment: The problem i'm having is that when I do it this way, when I try to add a value, it sets the entire row to that value.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a resizable dataset. You define them by using the `maxshape=()` parameter. None means unlimited length. Example below shows how to create a resizable dataset. It starts with the data from your question and first answer. After it exits the 1st `with/as:` block, there is a 2nd `with/as:` block that reopens the file (in append mode), extends the dataset, and adds 5 more rows of data.

Also, I modified the dtype definition used for the  recarray and resulting dataset. Previous code had all string values. I changed the 1st and 3rd columns to use integers (to match data values). It demonstrates how to mix datatypes in a recarray. Also, I I removed the create_group() call. Groups are not required (unless you want to use them to organize your datasets).

```
import numpy as np
import h5py

x1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
y1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
z1 = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
namesList = ['ID', 'Name', 'Path']
ds_dt = np.dtype({'names': namesList, 'formats': [int, 'S32', int] })

rec_arr = np.rec.fromarrays([x1, y1, z1], dtype=ds_dt)

with h5py.File("test.h5", "w") as h5f:
    h5f.create_dataset('data', data=rec_arr, maxshape=(None,),
                         compression='gzip' )
    
x2 = [ i for i in range(10,15)]
y2 = [chr(i) for i in  range(102,107)]
z2 = [ i for i in range(15,20)]
rec_arr = np.rec.fromarrays([x2, y2, z2], dtype=ds_dt)

with h5py.File("test.h5", "a") as h5f:
    ds_len = h5f['data'].shape[0]
    arr_len = rec_arr.shape[0]
    h5f['data'].resize(ds_len+arr_len,axis=0)
    h5f['data'][arr_len:ds_len+arr_len] = rec_arr
```